# Get Trigger.OldMap from TriggerHandler extended class

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working with TriggerHandler framework where I am extending the TriggerHandler class in apex class and calling it in Trigger. Source of the TriggerHandler class -  [Trigger Handler Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)

Question :

Normally we can able to get the **Trigger.OldMap** easily in trigger like below

```
for(Case caseLoop : Trigger.new){
   Case oldCase = Trigger.OldMap.get(caseLoop.id);
}
```

But how can I get the OldMap from the class that extends that TriggerHandler framework like below,

```
Public class className extends TriggerHandler{
   public override void afterUpdate() {
      afterUpdateLogics();
   }

   public static void afterUpdateLogics(){
      for(Case caseLoop : (List<Case>) Trigger.new){
          ***Needs to get the old map here****
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use it the same way -- Trigger.oldMap

Comment: No If I do like that it is throwing error saying that "Illegal assignment from SObject to Case"

Comment: You can use trigger context variables anywhere in apex, you just have to cast the result if it's outside of a trigger.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen show me which line is wrong.
Probably, you need to cast sObject to case:
**Case oldCase = (Case)Trigger.OldMap.get(caseLoop.id);**

Comment: kudos to @kurunve. It is a casting problem. Thanks for your answer. Please post it as answer so that I can tick as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to access trigger context variables is to cast generic sObject to concrete type, like:

```
Case oldCase = (CaseTrigger.OldMap.get(caseLoop.id);
```

`Trigger.OldMap`, as well as `Trigger.newMap`, has type `Map<Id, sObject>`.

In case if context variables are used in trigger - those may be automatically casted in proper trigger type, so next line of code is absolutely valid (if written in trigger):

```
Case oldCase = Trigger.OldMap.get(caseLoop.id);
```

Otherwise, compiler know nothing about scope of execution context, so in that situation it can not cast it automatically. As result, next code should be used:

```
Case oldCase = (Case)Trigger.OldMap.get(caseLoop.id);
```